# Multiple Overlay Movies in FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, movieclip

I was trying to make a 3 columns by 2 row overlay in FFMEG

I found this command which works great for a 2x2 movie overlay

```
ffmpeg.exe -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -i video3.mp4 -i video4.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:0]scale=iw/2:ih/2,pad=iw*2:ih*2[a];[1:0]scale=iw/2:ih/2[b];[2:0]scale=iw/2:ih/2[c];[3:0]scale=iw/2:ih/2[d];[a][b]overlay=w[x];[x][c]overlay=0:h[y];[y][d]overlay=w:h,drawtext=fontsize=12:fontcolor=white:fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:text='vid1':x=35:y=35,drawtext=fontsize=12:fontcolor=white:fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:text='vid2':x=(w/2)+35:y=35,drawtext=fontsize=12:fontcolor=white:fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:text='vid3':x=35:y=(h/2)+35,drawtext=fontsize=12:fontcolor=white:fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:text='vid4':x=(w/2)+35:y=(h/2)+35" output.mp4
```

(Same command just multiple lines only for readability)

```
ffmpeg.exe -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -i video3.mp4 -i video4.mp4 
-filter_complex "[0:0]scale=iw/2:ih/2,pad=iw*2:ih*2[a];[1:0]scale=iw/2:ih/2[b];
[2:0]scale=iw/2:ih/2[c];[3:0]scale=iw/2:ih/2[d];[a][b]overlay=w[x];
[x][c]overlay=0:h[y];[y][d]overlay=w:h,drawtext=fontsize=12:fontcolor=white:
fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:text='vid1':x=35:y=35,drawtext=fontsize=12:
fontcolor=white:fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:text='vid2':x=(w/2)+35:y=35,drawtext=fontsize=12:fontcolor=white:
 fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:text='vid3':x=35
:y=(h/2)+35,drawtext=fontsize=12:fontcolor=white:
fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:text='vid4':x=(w/2)+35:y=(h/2)+35" output.mp4
```

I had trouble adding the 2 other movies, I know you add this

```
ffmpeg.exe -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -i video3.mp4 -i video4.mp4 -i video5.mp4 -i video6.mp4
```

and this

```
-filter_complex "[0:0]scale=iw/2:ih/2,pad=iw*3:ih*2[a];
```

but positioning the last 2 movies and text is where I am lost

image per request [edit]
of what I want to do in organizing the overlays

[image: overlay of 6 videos 3x2 with text on top]

Comment: all inputs are same size

Comment: Can you provide an image to represent what you want to do?